# Bus Error 10 on Mac when creating a binary tree in C

Tags: c, macos, pointers, data-structures, binary-tree

I am getting bus error when I'm trying to create a binary tree using structures in C.
Please suggest me  a solution to overcome this bus error. I am compiling on Mac OSX.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct node* NewNode(int data) { 
  struct node* inode ;
  inode->data = data; 
  inode->left = NULL; 
  inode->right = NULL;
  printf("%d\n", inode->data);
  return(inode); 
}

struct node* insert(struct node* node ,int data){ 
    if(node == NULL)
        return(NewNode(data)); 
    else{
        if(data <= node->data)
            node->left = insert(node->left, data);
        else
            node->right = insert(node->right, data);
        return(node);
    }

}

struct node* build123a() { 
  struct node* root = newNode(2); 

  struct node* lChild = newNode(1); 
  struct node* rChild = newNode(3);
  root->left = lChild; 
  root->right= rChild;

  return(root); 
}

int main(void) {

    build123a();    

}
```

ouput : Bus Error 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `newNode` function you are defining the structure pointer `struct node* inode` but not allocating it. And then accessing it to store data, which is incorrect.

`inode` will have random value (which is taken as address) and when accessing that address, you may get bus error.

You need to allocate memory in your function, like

```
  struct node* NewNode(int data) { 
      struct node* inode ;
      inode = malloc(sizeof(*inode)); //allocate memory
      inode->data = data; 
      inode->left = NULL; 
      inode->right = NULL;
      printf("%d\n", inode->data);
      return(inode); 
  }
```